# Dockerfile should specify at least one CMD or ENTRYPOINT

Tags: python, docker

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
#CMD ["python", "src/train.py"]
```

For many reasons, a docker container is very useful, but I don't always need a `CMD` in the dockerfile. Right now, if I comment out `CMD ["python", "src/train.py"]` and building/running, the container never shows up. If I just build/running including `CMD ["python", "src/train.py"]` in the dockerfile, the container will exist just a fraction of a second because `python src/train.py` will create an error. How can I provide a dummy `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`? Be aware that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile explains `Dockerfile should specify at least one of CMD or ENTRYPOINT commands`.

**UPDATE**

I changed `CMD ["python", "src/train.py"]` by `ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]` and it works, but I am not sure it is a good solution (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775266/how-to-keep-docker-container-running-after-starting-services).

Answer (score 1):

Tailing `/dev/null` is valid (As is `["sleep", "inifity"]`) for development, debugging, and utility purposes.

Docker is *meant to* essentially wrap a running process. By doing things in the container outside of the CMD (If you're tailing dev null), you will not be able to access the logs through `docker logs`, and will not be able to use the docker ecosystem to verify the state of your process through the exit code which reflects in the state of the container.

If you don't have a single process that you are running in docker, then I'm not sure what benefit the container has vs using WSL. Although if it is the case that the image provides *general utility*, it would still be courteous to set the default entrypoint as `bash` so that you can enter a shell, ensuring you pass in `-it` when running.

You need to specify what you're using the container for, as that will help ascertain whether your current setup is a good solution (to a problem we are currently unaware about), and what may be best

Comment: I run different case scenarios for debug and development purposes inside the container. I just need to hold the container as I do with `ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]`

Comment: Neat! If you're using containers for the purposes of providing a utility environment, then letting the running process be sleep sounds like it won't hinder you. It's important to take into account that if you wanted your image to be utilised for a single service, like an app or a db, then using a single process through CMD becomes a better practice